# Не работают эвенты редактора круга

Tags: yandex-maps-api

мне нужно понимать в какой момент радиус/позиция круга изменяется через редактор(editor)
по какой-то причине ни один из эвентов не срабатывает, кроме drag, в чем может быть проблема?

```
const myCircle = new this.ymaps.Circle(
            [
                // Координаты центра круга.
                [55.76, 37.6],
                // Радиус круга в метрах.
                10000,
            ],
            {},
            {
                // Задаем опции круга.
                // Цвет заливки.
                fillColor: '#DB709377',
                // Цвет обводки.
                strokeColor: '#990066',
                // Прозрачность обводки.
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                // Ширина обводки в пикселях.
                strokeWidth: 5,
            }
        );

        this.map.geoObjects.add(myCircle);

        myCircle.editor.startEditing();
        myCircle.editor.events.add(['drag','vertexdragend', 'vertexdrag', 'edgedrag', 'statechange'], function (e) {
            console.log(e);
            console.log(myCircle.editor.events);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

пока не написал, не решил проблему :/
однако, решать что изменилось придется, видимо, как-то кастомно

решение

```
myCircle.events.add(['geometrychange'], function (e) {
            console.log('resized or dragged');
        });
```